# Audio Waveform Synthesizer in C++ that outputs to soundcard. Where do I begin?

Tags: c++, audio

I managed to write a PCM sine wave synthesizer in Java using the javax package. Basically, the program generates a sine wave at a sample rate of 44100, and writes the byte data to the SourceDataLine.

I'm trying to achieve the same thing in C++ but I have not been able to find any answers here that **do not** require the use of an extensive library such as OpenAL.

I would like to know if it is possible to send byte data directly to the sound card using just the Standard library.

[working on windows 10 and Netbeans IDE]

Comment: Like starmole says, audio would be platform dependent. If you want an answer for your particular platform, we would need to know what that is.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

You will need a platform library. Audio is very finicky and platform dependent. If I can suggest an alternative: Look into writing a VST plugin!

Comment: Thanks starmole and Dave, so that means I need some sort of windows library that would give me some sort of API to interface with my platform's audio functionality right? I've been reading up on the windows audio API here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370784(v=vs.85).aspx 
Would you say I'm looking in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like a good article, though possibly dated. I have been boggled by the same issue. Have written many Java audio programs (including FM synth) and effects, astounded to find out that I was taking SourceDataLine for granted. Another idea to investigate: there's been some recent activity with new sound programming with Unreal Engine, and access to source code is provided. I plan to do some research there when I get a chance. I will be following this thread.